# Made a calculator, need text to turn red when the value is negative

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I have to make a themed calculator for class, so I randomly chose Xmas. Ignore that part haha. One requirement is that my text has to turn red when the output value of the calc. is negative, so I made an if loop in the JavaScript section. It won't work and I've been at it forever. Is there something wrong with the loop?? Thanks

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>




   { function sum(){
        var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
        var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
        var Box3 = Box1 + Box2
        document.getElementById("Box3").value = Box3
        {if (Box3>0){
       Box3.style.color = rgb(60, 179, 113)}
    else {Box3.style.color = rgb(255, 0, 0)}}
    }
    function minus(){
        var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
        var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
        var Box3 = Box1 - Box2
        document.getElementById("Box3").value = Box3
    }

    function divide(){
        var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
        var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
        var Box3 = Box1/Box2
        document.getElementById("Box3").value = Box3     
    }
    function mult(){
        var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
        var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
        var Box3 = Box1 * Box2
        document.getElementById("Box3").value = Box3     
    }
    function powers(){
        var result= 1
        var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
        var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
        for (i = 0; i < Box2; i++) { 
            result = result * Box1
        }
        document.getElementById("Box3").value = result  

        }
   function erase(){  
    document.getElementById('Box1').value = "";
    document.getElementById('Box2').value = ""; 
    document.getElementById('Box3').value = "";
   }
        {if (Box3>0){
       Box3.style.color = rgb(60, 179, 113)}
    else {Box3.style.color = rgb(255, 0, 0)}
   }

   }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <font face="KR Cane Letters" size="50" color="red">Welcome</font>
    <div>
    </div>
    <font face="KR Cane Letters" size="50" color="green">to the CHRISTMAS Calculator!!!</font>
    <div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="Box1">
    <input type="text" id="Box2">
    <p>=</p>
    <input type="text" id="Box3">
    <button onclick="sum()">+</button> 
    <button onclick="minus()">-</button> 
    <button onclick="divide()">/</button>
    <button onclick="mult()">*</button>
    <button onclick="powers()">^</button>
    <button onclick="erase()">Erase</button>


     <style type="text/css">body, a:hover {cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/holidays/hol-5/hol441.ani), url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/holidays/hol-5/hol441.gif), progress !important;}</style><a href="http://www.cursors-4u.com/cursor/2011/12/17/decorated-green-christmas-tree.html" target="_blank" title="Decorated Green Christmas Tree"><img src="http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursor.png" border="0" alt="Decorated Green Christmas Tree" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;" /></a>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please fix your errors and format your code first. Also, you don't just put everything inside of `{` and `}`. Those delimiters are for a variety of things, but not all code.

Comment: Start by [opening the browser console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) and looking at the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your code, but you should really listen to the comments - even if you don't want to format your code by hand dropping it into, for example, http://jsbeautifier.org/ is not that hard.

Also, do note that curly brackets ("{" and "}") have a specific purpose, and you should end your lines with a semicolon (";").

```js
function sum() {
    var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
    var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
    var Box3 = Box1 + Box2;
    document.getElementById("Box3").value = Box3;
    colourBox3(Box3);
}

function minus() {
    var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
    var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
    var Box3 = Box1 - Box2;
    document.getElementById("Box3").value = Box3;
    colourBox3(Box3);
}

function divide() {
    var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
    var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
    var Box3 = Box1 / Box2;
    document.getElementById("Box3").value = Box3;
    colourBox3(Box3);
}

function mult() {
    var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
    var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
    var Box3 = Box1 * Box2;
    document.getElementById("Box3").value = Box3;
    colourBox3(Box3);
}

function powers() {
    var result = 1
    var Box1 = Number(document.getElementById("Box1").value);
    var Box2 = Number(document.getElementById("Box2").value);
    for (i = 0; i < Box2; i++) {
        result = result * Box1;
    }
    document.getElementById("Box3").value = result;
    colourBox3(result);
}

function erase() {
    document.getElementById('Box1').value = "";
    document.getElementById('Box2').value = "";
    document.getElementById('Box3').value = "";
}

function colourBox3(val) {
    if (val > 0) {
        document.getElementById("Box3").style.color = "rgb(60, 179, 113)";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Box3").style.color = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <font face="KR Cane Letters" size="50" color="red">Welcome</font>
    <div>
    </div>
    <font face="KR Cane Letters" size="50" color="green">to the CHRISTMAS Calculator!!!</font>
    <div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="Box1">
    <input type="text" id="Box2">
    <p>=</p>
    <input type="text" id="Box3">
    <button onclick="sum()">+</button> 
    <button onclick="minus()">-</button> 
    <button onclick="divide()">/</button>
    <button onclick="mult()">*</button>
    <button onclick="powers()">^</button>
    <button onclick="erase()">Erase</button>


     <style type="text/css">body, a:hover {cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/holidays/hol-5/hol441.ani), url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/holidays/hol-5/hol441.gif), progress !important;}</style><a href="http://www.cursors-4u.com/cursor/2011/12/17/decorated-green-christmas-tree.html" target="_blank" title="Decorated Green Christmas Tree"><img src="http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursor.png" border="0" alt="Decorated Green Christmas Tree" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;" /></a>




</body>

</html>
```